Rebuilt text view to include @ mentions not spanning full width
To make my @ mentions clickable and navigate to a profile, I've had to rebuild the text view to make sure anything including an @ is clickable. While this way of doing it looks okay most of the time, sometimes (if a word is close to being at the horizontal cutoff) it wraps early when a normal text view would not do that. I know it would not because the way I am deciding how much vertical space to give it is by putting a clear line of text behind it with the caption text. When it wraps too early, the next comment in the view is pushed on top of the one with the TextWithMention view. Originally, I had the opposite problem where words would stay on the first line even if only one letter fit, so I added code to fix that but caused this new problem where words are wrapping too soon.
This seems like a hacky way of doing things but I haven't found any better way so I am open to other solutions also. Here are my only requirements really and maybe I've overcomplicated it:

It should take up the same amount of space and rebuild just like a line of text would (wrap when a line of text wraps & visually look the same as a line of text)
I need to detect @ mentions and then make them clickable to navigate to that users profile (it should work even when you have multiple @'s in one comment)

TextWithMentions
struct TextWithMentions: View {
    let commentText: String
    @Binding var needsDismissed: Bool
    
    @State private var mentionedUsers: [User] = []
    @State private var sizes: [CGSize] = []
    @EnvironmentObject var navigationManager: NavigationManager
    @State private var selection: String? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        MultilineHStack(views: extractMentions(from: commentText).map { component in
            buildTextView(for: component)
        })
        .task {
            fetchMentionedUsers()
        }
    }
    
    private func buildTextView(for component: Component) -> AnyView {
        switch component {
        case .normal(let text):
            return AnyView(
                Text("\(text) ")
                    .font(Font.caption)
            )
        case .mention(let username, let user):
            return AnyView(
                Text("@\(username) ")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.accentColor)
                    .font(Font.caption)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if let user = user {
                            navigationManager.goTo(destination: .profile(user))
                            needsDismissed = true
                            selection = username
                        }
                    }
            )
        case .mentionPlaceholder(let username):
            return AnyView(
                Text("@\(username) ")
                    .font(Font.caption)
            )
        }
    }
    
    private func extractMentions(from text: String) -> [Component] {
        let words = text.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        var components: [Component] = []
        
        for word in words {
            if word.hasPrefix("@") {
                let username = String(word.dropFirst())
                if let user = mentionedUsers.first(where: { $0.username == username }) {
                    components.append(.mention(username: username, user: user))
                } else {
                    components.append(.mentionPlaceholder(username: username))
                }
            } else {
                components.append(.normal(text: word))
            }
        }
        
        return components
    }
    
    private func fetchMentionedUsers() {
        let usernames = mentionedUsernames(from: commentText)
        
        print("usernames: \(usernames)")
        
        // Check if there are @mentions before making a query
        if !usernames.isEmpty {
            fetchMentionedUsers(usernames: usernames) { fetchedUsers in
                mentionedUsers = fetchedUsers
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func mentionedUsernames(from text: String) -> [String] {
        let words = text.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        return words.filter { $0.hasPrefix("@") }.map { String($0.dropFirst()) }
    }
    
    private func fetchMentionedUsers(usernames: [String], completion: @escaping ([User]) -> Void) {
        let query = COLLECTION_USERS.whereField("username", in: usernames)
        
        query.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching mentioned users: \(error)")
                completion([])
                return
            }
            
            let mentionedUsers = snapshot?.documents.compactMap {
                try? $0.data(as: User.self)
            } ?? []
            
            print("Users fetched: \(mentionedUsers)")
            
            completion(mentionedUsers)
        }
    }
}


enum Component {
    case normal(text: String)
    case mention(username: String, user: User?)
    case mentionPlaceholder(username: String)
}


extension View {
    func eraseToAnyView() -> AnyView {
        AnyView(self)
    }
}

public struct MultilineHStack: View {
    struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
        typealias Value = [CGSize]
        static var defaultValue: Value = []
        static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
            value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
        }
    }

    private let views: [AnyView]
    @State private var sizes: [CGSize] = []

    public init(views: [AnyView]) {
        self.views = views
    }

    public var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                    ForEach(self.views.indices) { index in
                        self.views[index].background(self.backgroundView(index: index))
                            .offset(self.getOffset(at: index, availableWidth: geometry.size.width))
                    }
                }
                .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) {
                    self.sizes = $0
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func backgroundView(index: Int) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.clear)
                .preference(
                    key: SizePreferenceKey.self,
                    value: [geometry.size]
                )
        }
    }

    private func calculateTotalHeight() -> CGFloat {
        let totalHeight = sizes.map { $0.height }.reduce(0, +) + CGFloat(sizes.count - 1) * 4
        return totalHeight
    }

    private func getOffset(at index: Int, availableWidth: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        guard index < sizes.endIndex else { return .zero }

        var (x, y) = sizes[..<index].reduce((CGFloat.zero, CGFloat.zero)) { (currentOffset, size) in
            let (currentX, currentY) = currentOffset

            // Check if adding the current word width exceeds the available width
            if currentX + size.width <= availableWidth {
                // If it fits within the line, add its width to the x offset
                return (currentX + size.width, currentY)
            } else {
                // If it exceeds the available width, move to the next line
                return (size.width, currentY + size.height) // Move to the next line
            }
        }

        // If any part of the word extends outside of the available width, move the entire word to the next line
        let wordWidth = sizes[index].width
        if x + wordWidth > availableWidth {
            // Move to the next line
            x = 0
            y += sizes[index].height
            
            // Shift subsequent words to the next line
            let remainingSizes = sizes[index...]
            for i in index..<sizes.endIndex {
                sizes[i].height += sizes[index].height
            }
        }

        return CGSize(width: x, height: y)
    }

    private func calculateMaxWidth(availableWidth: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return availableWidth
    }
}


In my view
struct CommentCell: View {
    let commentText = "@john I need to go to the store soon with @jane"
    @State private var needsDismissed = false
    var hasMentions: Bool { return commentText.contains("@") }

    var body: some View {
        if self.hasMentions {
            Text(commentText)
                .foregroundStyle(Color.clear)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .font(Font.caption)
                .overlay(
                    TextWithMentions(commentText: commentText, needsDismissed: $needsDismissed)
                )
        } else {
            Text(commentText)
                .font(Font.caption)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        }
    }
}




Please include a [mre]. No one can run the code you included 2) You should watch Demystify SwiftUI from WWDC to learn why AnyView is generally not recommended. You should use @ViewBuilder instead of AnyView for your branching statements


I would just use AttributedString/markdown. You can find them using RegEx and replace with a markdown url.
